# Blazor WASM client index.html without MainLayout

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly, azure-static-web-app

Blazor WASM client application deploys to Azure Static Web App and displays the index.html without any of the Shared pages or MainLayout.  There is allowannoymous attribute applied to page and project works well in development localhost.

Tried to remove the authorization from the index.html page.  Provided an update information label to verify that all code changes are applying to deployment.  Inspected the developer tools and have zero css errors with only one error to ./wellknown/ path for oidc authentication.

Comment: There is no way anyone can answer this question based on the information provided.  Create a out-of-the-box application and deploy it.  Check it works and then progressively add your code until you break it.  There's no silver bullet path.

Comment: Since we don't have enough information to reproduce the issue, I shared what I test below and pls take a look at it. If I misunderstood your issue, pls correct me or add more details in your question..

Comment: Do you mean `Index.razor` or `Home.razor` perhaps? `index.html` is only used to download the WASM content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't reproduce your issue in my side and pls allow me share what I test here.

Firstly, I create a blazor webassembly project with Microsoft identity platform without asp.net core hosted. Because you didn't mention the authentication scheme you used.

[image]

After modify the properties related to Azure AD in appsettings.json in wwwroot folder, I'm able to have the sign in option in the layout. Then no matter added `@attribute [Authorize]` in the `index.razor` or in the `MainLayout.razor`, the app and the authentication both worked well, if I had `@attribute [Authorize]` in the `index.razor`, the app would redirect to the sign in page automatically when I hit the home page.

Then I followed the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-7.0#deploy-from-visual-studio) to publish the app to azure static website. It worked as well.

[image]

Comment: Using IdentityServer yet all works on development .  This sounds like the best solution. Thanks Tiny Wang.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply ChrisR : )